# typescript autocompletion in javascript

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, typescript

I have been converting an existing Javascript application to Typescript. I started with the DataController, one of the most used classes in the app. I added it to my tsd.d.ts file and added a reference tag at the top, but I do not get autocompletion in the existing Javascript file where the DataController is instantiated.

Am I doing something wrong, or does Typescript only provide autocompletion in other Typescript files?

I am using VSCode.

Comment: Your source file must have a .ts extension.

Comment: Do you mean the file where DataController is declared must have a .ts extension or the file where it is instantiated must have one? I set the .ts extension on the former but not on the latter

Comment: Yes the file you instantiate it. The Typescript compiler only works on .ts files. You can only reference other .ts files or write code in .ts files to get the compiler benefits. It doesn't do anything with .js files.

Comment: @pixelmike Add it as an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 2):

> does Typescript only provide autocompletion in other Typescript files?

Yes